# Missing bond type in chemical rendering packages?

Tags: chemfig

I've read all the questions regarding chemical structure rendering that I could find on this website. I've decided to use `chemfig` to render the structures.

One certain type of bond, illustrated below, is missing from every chemical structure rendering package. How would I make the following type of bond?

[image]

Comment: The variable position bond really should start at the centre of the ring (probably makes it even more tricky to do!)

Comment: No, less tricky : just remove the `shorten` key in my code.

Comment: @JosephWright I know, but for some reason ChemDraw didn't let me do that... and since I'm interested in doing this in LaTeX, I didn't spend more time on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest this method:

```
\chemfig{*6(-=-(-[,-1,,,draw=none]-[0,1.5,,,
shorten <= 10pt,preaction={draw=white,line width=6pt}]X)=-=)}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup!