# chemical scheme not elegant

Tags: chemfig

I want to make this chemical scheme: [image]

I try with this code. But not very elegant. Somebody can I help me ?

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
    \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{chemformula}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}


    \begin{document}


\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} + \ch{H2O}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Hidrólise]}
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} + \ch{H2O}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Condensação]}
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH}
\schemestop

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `mychemistry` package could help.

Comment: Thank you for providing a complete example. It might help if you could provide a *minimal* example - the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem you have. For instance, you load the `chemformula` package twice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this. I have modified the interatomic separation and the length of the arrows in the scheme. If this is not what you want, please explain what you mean by "elegant" :-) NB: `\quad` and `\;` are for horizontal spacing on the lines

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setatomsep{2em} %<-- Add this for atom spacing
\schemestart[0,1.5] %<-- Add the optional argument here to specify the angle (0) and length of the arrows
a) \quad \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} + \ch{H2O}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Hidrólise]}
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH} + \ch{HOR}
\schemestop

\vspace*{0.5cm} %<-- Add this for vertical spacing

\schemestart[0,1.75]
b) \quad 2 \; \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Condensação]}
\chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-O-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} + \ch{H2O}
\schemestop

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: chemfig]

Comment: fantastic! thank you. Just one more thing. I want to put numbers or letters to identify each reaction. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you simply want letters on each line, just type them there :-) If you want to be able to refer to them with `\ref` and similar, have a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114933/32374 to define a new floating type and you may also need to look at the documentation of the [`subfig`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) package to see how to add new types of subfigures.

Comment: I want letters on each line, but centered

Comment: Just put them inside the scheme. See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

»not very elegant« is not a very precise description of what's wrong...

First of all I'd use a list for the, well, list, i.e., `enumerate`. The labels can easily be adjusted with [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Then I'd make the arrows longer using the last optional argument of the `\arrow` command:

```
\arrow[<angle>,<length factor>]
```

I'd also shorten the bond length a bit, maybe `\setatomsep{2em}`.

Last but not least I'd use `chemfig`'s `\+` command in the schemes for a bit more spacing around the compounds.

Then I get this (the lines just show the page dimensions so we're sure nothing sticks into the margin):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}% not necessary for the example
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}% already loaded by chemmacros
\usepackage{chemfig}
% \usepackage{chemmacros}% not necessary for the example

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}% to visualize page dimensions

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item\setatomsep{2em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} \+ \ch{H2O}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Hidrólise]}[,2]
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH}
  \schemestop
  \item
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} \+ \ch{H2O}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Condensação]}[,2]
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH}
  \schemestop
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Of course the chemistry is still wrong but that was not your question, right? After correcting it the equations got a little but too long but that can be fixed by adjusting the lengths of the arrows and the bonds:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}% not necessary for the example
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}% already loaded by chemmacros
\usepackage{chemfig}
% \usepackage{chemmacros}% not necessary for the example

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}% to visualize page dimensions

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item\setatomsep{1.8em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} \+ \ch{H2O}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Hidrólise]}[,1.8]
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OH} \+ \ch{HOR}
  \schemestop
  \item
  \schemestart
    2 \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[ Condensação]}[,1.8]
    \chemfig{RO-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-O-Si(-[6]OR)(-[2]OR)-OR} \+ \ch{H2O}
  \schemestop
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]