# Attach atom to center of ring in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Sometimes chemists want to signify that something is attached to a C-ring without specifying the exact position to which it is bound, for example because it's random. Instead they to something like

[image: this]

(see the R^1). This could also be attached to the center of the ring or the "aromatic circle" in the bottom left. Can this be done in `chemfig`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Since `chemfig` v1.56, center of a ring can be easily referenced as a node name. See update near the end of this answer.)

Yes `chemfig` can do this, with some tricks (or advanced usage?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} \qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=(-[:150])-=-=)} \qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=(-[:150]-[:120]-[:120]R^1)-=-=)} \qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=(-[:150]-[:120,.5]-[:120]R^1)-=-=)} \qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=(-[:150,,,,white]-[:120,.5,,,draw=none]-[:120]R^1)-=-=)}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Start.
  \item Draw a bond to center with syntax \verb|-[<angle>]|.
  \item Draw two more bonds to get to the right angle, and add desired atom.
  \item Adjust bond length using syntax \verb|-[<angle>,<length scale>]|.
  \item Hide intermediate bonds by specifying a white drawing color, 
        using syntax \verb|-[<angle>,<length scale>,,,<tikz code>]|.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

In the following example, an arc inside ring is named `A`, so the center of ring is `(A.center)`. I do not know how to draw a `chemfig` bond starting at arbitrary coordinate, so I use `insert path`.

Limitation: Angle needs to be explicitly specified, like the `36` in `(36:5pt)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{%
  **[,,draw=none, local bounding box=A]%
  5(-----%
    [,,,,{insert path={
      ([shift={(36:5pt)}]A.center) -- +(36:1cm) node[anchor=center, right] {X}
    }}]%
  )%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update 2

With `chemfig` v1.56 (or newer), the center of ring can be referred by node name `centrecycle<n>`, see the [`chemfig` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), sec. 12.6 for more detail. Thanks to Christian Tellechea, author of `chemfig`.

The following example contains two `\chemfig` drawings.

- In the first one, drawing commands among cycle center is added by the following `\chemmove`, which won't extend the bounding box of previous `\chemfig` and might overlap with surrounding text.
- The second one moves those drawing commands among cycle center to `tikz` option `execute at end picture`, which do extends the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{
  % helper style
  show bounding box/.style={
    execute at end picture={
      \draw[blue, #1] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[23]

Example from \verb|chemfig| manual, sec.\@ 12.6. Note \verb|\chemmove| won't extend the bounding box.

text
\chemfig[chemfig style={show bounding box}]{*6(-=-=-=)}%
\chemmove{
  \node[at=(cyclecenter1)] {.+}
   node[at=(cyclecenter1), shift=(120:1.75cm)] (end) {\printatom{R^1}};
  \draw[-, shorten <=.5cm] (cyclecenter1) -- (end);
}
text

Using \verb|execute at end picture|, the bounding box is correctly extended.

\tikzset{
  cycle center staff/.style={
    execute at end picture={
      \path (cyclecenter1) node[anchor=center] {.+}
           +(120:1.75cm)   node[inner sep=2pt] (end) {\printatom{R^1}};
      \draw (cyclecenter1) +(120:.5cm) -- (end);
    }
  }
}

text \chemfig[chemfig style={
  cycle center staff,
  show bounding box
}]{*6(-=-=-=)}
text

\lipsum[23]
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update 3

To simplify user input, a new command `\chempremove` is defined. With this new command,

```
\chempremove{<tikz drawing code>}
\chemfig{...}
```

is equivalent to

```
\chemfige[chemfig style={execute at end picture={<tikz drawing code>}}]{...}
```

Full implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\tikzset{
  % helper style
  show bounding box/.style={
    execute at end picture={
      \draw[blue, #1] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    }
  }
}

% new command \chempremove{<tikz code executed at end picture>}
\catcode`\_=11\relax

\defKV[chemfig]{%
  at end picture        = \def\CF_atendpic_once{#1},
  at end picture append = \CF_addtomacro\CF_atendpic_once{#1}
}
\setKVdefault[chemfig]{%
  at end picture        = {}
}

\newcommand{\chempremove}[1]{%
  \setKV[chemfig]{at end picture append={#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\xpatchcmd\CF_chemfigb
  {baseline,}
  {baseline,%
   execute at end picture={\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_atendpic_once}},}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\CF_chemfigb
  {\let\CF_flipstate\CF_zero}
  {\let\CF_flipstate\CF_zero\let\CF_atendpic_once\empty}
  {}{\fail}

\catcode`\_=8\relax

\begin{document}
\lipsum[23]

Example from \verb|chemfig| manual, sec.\@ 12.6. Note \verb|\chemmove| won't extend the bounding box.

\chempremove{
  % show bounding box
  \draw[blue] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
}

text
\chemfig[chemfig style={show bounding box}]{*6(-=-=-=)}%
\chemmove{
  \node[at=(cyclecenter1)] {.+}
   node[at=(cyclecenter1), shift=(120:1.75cm)] (end) {\printatom{R^1}};
  \draw[-, shorten <=.5cm] (cyclecenter1) -- (end);
}
text

Using \verb|\chempremove|, the bounding box is correctly extended.

\chempremove{
  \path (cyclecenter1) node[anchor=center] {.+}
       +(120:1.75cm)   node[inner sep=2pt] (end) {\printatom{R^1}};
  \draw (cyclecenter1) +(120:.5cm) -- (end);
  % show bounding box
  \draw[blue] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
}

text \chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} text

\lipsum[23]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well, however the answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84130/missing-bond-type-in-chemical-rendering-packages) did it a bit more elegantly. However, both seem to only work well for 6-rings where the "bond" to the center has "normal" length. Is there not a way to utilize the ring center directly, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156483/plus-sign-in-the-middle-of-a-ring)?

Comment: @MatthiasvomBruch You mean a general ring-center, for example center of 5-ring?

Comment: @muzimzuhi Z - Yes, exactly, that would be very neat

Comment: @NoBullsh1t I added an complex example to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can open an issue under https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/-/issues/.

Comment: @NoBullsh1t Hi, `chemfig` v1.56 has added nodes at ring centers. See "Update 2" part in my answer.

Comment: Pretty complex but does what I wanted! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NoBullsh1t Hi, I added a new command `\chempremove` in **Update 3**. Hope that simplifies user input a little bit